# Haskell Tokens in expression `A._`

Tags: haskell, syntax, typed-holes

How does Haskell interpret the expression `A._`?
E.g. in `main = print $ A._`.

Haskell throws the following error error:

```
source_file.hs:1:16:
    Found hole ‘_’ with type: r0
    Where: ‘r0’ is an ambiguous type variable
    Relevant bindings include
      main :: IO ()
        (bound at source_file.hs:1:1)
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘A._’
    In the expression: print $ A._
    In an equation for ‘main’: main = print $ A._
```

However, according to Haskell's [Syntax Reference](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html), `A._` should be interpreted as `consym (A)`, `varsym (.)` and `reservedid (_)`, since `_` is not a valid `varid` (`varid`s cannot be `reservedid`s).

Haskell throws the same error for `main = print $ A._t`:

```
source_file.hs:1:16:
    Found hole ‘_t’ with type: r0
    Where: ‘r0’ is an ambiguous type variable
    Relevant bindings include
      main :: IO ()
        (bound at source_file.hs:1:1)
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘A._t’
    In the expression: print $ A._t
    In an equation for ‘main’: main = print $ A._t
```

In this case however, the token sequence should be `qvarid (A._t)` as `A` matches `modid` and `_t` matches `varid`.

Can anybody help me out and explain what is going on?

Comment: could you include the full contents of `source_file.hs`.

Comment: The source file does not contain anything else. I am currently trying to implement an haskell parser in typescript and for that I need to understand the behavior in this case.

Comment: What version of GHC are you using?

Comment: Are these the only errors you are getting?

Comment: I have been using this [online tool](http://rextester.com/l/haskell_online_compiler) which is `The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.3`.
The mentioned error is the only one.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in ghc:
`data A = B | C A deriving Show; main = print ((C.let x = (\arg -> B) in x) B)`
does not compile (it throws `parse error on input ‘=’`), but `data A = B | C A deriving Show; main = print ((C . let x = (\arg -> B) in x) B)` does.
According to the syntax reference, both should compile, as `C.let` does not match `qvarid` (`let` is a `reservedid`).

Answer (score 5):

These are [typed holes](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#typed-holes), which are part of a GHC extension enabled by default. From this link:

> Typed holes are a feature of GHC that allows special placeholders written with a leading underscore (e.g., “`_`”, “`_foo`”, “`_bar`”), to be used as expressions. During compilation these holes will generate an error message that describes which type is expected at the hole’s location, information about the origin of any free type variables, and a list of local bindings that might help fill the hole with actual code. Typed holes are always enabled in GHC.

That means that `A._` gets parsed as an application of composition, `(.)`, to the constructor `A` and the typed hole expression `_`. The same holds for `A._t`.

The purpose of typed holes is mostly debugging: it lets you know what type GHC infers an expression in that position should have and reports that in an error message.

Comment: Are you sure `A` is interpreted as type constructor, I am getting errors about a missing import `A` - it is hard to figure this without the full source code.

Comment: at [begriffs.com](https://begriffs.com/posts/2015-02-07-haskell-type-holes.html) there is a video which shows the power and usage of type(d) holes in (AGDA and) Haskell

Comment: @epsilonhalbe I actually expected errors about a module `A` - my answer is just based on OPs error message. I reckon this probably comes down to a GHC version difference.

Comment: `I reckon this probably comes down to a GHC version difference.` those are  the things I _never_ think of - good idea.

Comment: It isn't attempting to specifically match the type of `_` against a function type though. That makes me think it's interpreting `A` as a module name.

Comment: What do you mean with `special placeholders`? I thought `_` is treated as a lower case letter, thus `_foo` should be a valid variable identifier, shouldn't it? Only a single `_` behaves differently, as `_` is a reserved id and varid's cannot be reservedid's (=> `_foo` is not a reserved id).

GHC does not seem to have a problem with

`main = print $ _a; _a = 32`

- it outputs 32 without any compiler errors/warnings.
However, just `main = print $ _a` yields the same error as `main = print $ _` as mentioned before.

Comment: @Henning It depends on whether `_a` is bound or unbound. If it is unbound, it is treated as a "named" [type hole](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#typed-holes).